# Unable to load property from application.yml - Junit5

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, junit, junit5

I am writing a Junit test case for a Component’s method that gets a property from application.yml file, this method works without any issue when I run the spring boot application but fails when run junit test cases, following is the error when I run through Junit:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.core.env.Environment.getProperty(String)" because "this.environment" is null
    at com.ylm.cnpl.core.util.EnvUtil.getEnvValue(EnvUtil.java:86)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:688)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:206)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:131)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:65)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:75)
at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
```

> **Application.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.ylm.cnpl.core"})
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

> **EnvUtil.java**

```
@Component
public class EnvUtil {
    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;
    
    public String getEnvValue(String key){
        return environment.getProperty(key);
    }
}
```

> **EnvUtilTest.java**

```
@SpringBootTest
public class EnvUtilTest {
    @Autowired
    private EnvUtil envUtil;
    @Mock
    Environment env;
    @Test
    public void getValueFromEnvConfigTest(){
        // THE BELOW LINE FIXED THE ISSUE!!!
        Mockito.when(env.getProperty(Mockito.any())).thenReturn("ADM");
        String envConfigValue = this.envUtil.getEnvValue("center.office.dept");
        assertNotNull(envConfigValue);
    }
}
```

I have tried following options on my Test class but no luck, any idea where I am wrong here?

1. adding following to my Test class

> ```
> @ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.ylm.cnpl.core"})
> ```

2. Try to load properties file explicitly

> ```
> @TestPropertySource(properties = { "spring.config.location=classpath:application.yml" })
> ```

3. Try to load as spring profiles, rename application.yml to application-test.yml and specified test profile

> ```
> @ActiveProfiles("test")
> ```

[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/faR87.png)
Here is the dependency i have included in my springboot project

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.ylm.cnpl.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>cnpl-common</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

**Update:**

Mocking the environment explicitly worked

```
// THE BELOW LINE FIXED THE ISSUE!!!
Mockito.when(env.getProperty(Mockito.any())).thenReturn("ADM");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `EnvUtil` class is not a Spring bean, the `@Bean` annotation is not applicable to type. Since the `EnvUtil` is not a bean, Spring cannot inject the `Environment` bean into it.

Try changing it to @Component like this:

```java
@Component
public class EnvUtil {
    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;
    
    public String getEnvValue(String key){
        return environment.getProperty(key);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am having the same issue with Component too, it was originally component not a bean I have correct the typo in the question

Comment: How does your application.yml file looks like?

Comment: I have a working example at https://github.com/Rashin46/stackoverflow-solutions/tree/main/70030061

Comment: Thank you for efforts put together the code on gitgub I really appreciate it. The Util module is in a common framework and using as reference in my pom.xml, the common module is used in a spring-boot project may be that is the issue?

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem; if it is in the same (sub)package as what you scanning ```@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.ylm.cnpl.core"})```.

Comment: Good point but no luck even I updated to make both springboot and shared module in same package changed from  
> **@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.ylm.cnpl.core"})**
to 
> **@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.ylm.cnpl"})**

Comment: The common module and the module that you are trying to run the test is in the same multi-module project? Could you provide a hierarchy of your project?

Comment: I have included the project structure in the question at the end

Comment: The ```EnvUtilTest``` is in the cnpl-common, right? Since the main ```Application``` is in the other module, you would need to add ```EnvUtil``` manually as a component to be loaded. Try with ```@SpringBootTest(classes = EnvUtil.class)```. Also, the application.yml file is only in the other module as well? I would copy it to the test resources in the cnpl-common.

Comment: I have added @SpringBootTest(classes = EnvUtil.class) to my test class and it is failing to load other components

   >Description:
    
    Field adamsTagRepository in com.ylm.cnpl.adams.service.AdamsTagServiceImpl required a bean of type 'com.ylm.cnpl.core.repository.AdamsTagRepository' that could not be found.
    
    The injection point has the following annotations:
     - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)**

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** Sorry about the previous answer, I misunderstood the original question and thought you just wanted to pull a property from application.yml file for your tests.

So here you are writing a unit test for the `envUtil.getEnvValue()` method. Therefore you should not actually call the `environment.getProperty()` method in your test but instead mock the Environment class and write a statement `when(environment.getProperty(anyString())).thenReturn("property");`

Unit tests are supposed to only test the particular method not the further methods that are getting called.

Comment: where is the EnvUtil component in your suggestion? The intention is to test the components method that is getting property.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your application.yml is located in test/resources folder

Comment: Yes it is in test/resources

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).